# java android - iterate JSON objects in array

Tags: java, android, json

How can i iterate over all of the "listPages" in this JSON object?

```
  {
        "listPages": [
            {
                "title": "Accounts",
                "recordType": "Company",
            },
            {
                "title": "Contacts",
                "recordType": "Person",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm trying to add list items to a list from each item in the listPages array via this code:

```
    JSONObject JSONConfig = envConfig.getEnvConfig(this);

    try{
        JSONArray listPages = JSONConfig.getJSONArray("listPages");         
        for(int i = 0 ; i < listPages.length() ; i++){
            listItems.add(listPages.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can see in logcat that i'm getting a system error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" on the following line.

```
JSONArray listPages = JSONConfig.getJSONArray("listPages");
```

I've tried reading and tweaking things from other questions but i can't figure it out. Help would be much appreciated.

here is my envConfig.java class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class EnvConfig {

    private String rawJSONString;
    private JSONObject jsonObjRecv;

    public JSONObject getEnvConfig(Context context){
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.envconfigg);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        rawJSONString = sb.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(rawJSONString);
            Log.i("Test", "<JSONObject>\n" + jsonObjRecv.toString()
                    + "\n</JSONObject>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObjRecv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `envConfig.getEnvConfig(this);`? Have you verified that it is returning a valid `JSONArray` object?

Comment: yes. first thing i did was run it through json lint

Comment: jsonlint is an external tools. I am referring to the method in your code - `envConfig.getEnvConfig(this);`. Print out the value you get from this method prior to entering your for loop.

Comment: yeah, i'm logging it to logcat and everything looks fine when its being logged.

Comment: It seems to me that the JSONObject returned in the first line is probably null.  Meaning you never successfully parsed the JSON.

Comment: i've updated my post with the code that creates the json object.

Comment: hmmm...i've moved the log line out of the envconfig.java class and right after i call envConfig.getEnvConfig(this) in the main class and the app crashes. Not sure what's going on

Comment: figured it out. For some reason in my envconfig class, the jsonObjRecv object never gets returned. If i move the "return jsonObjRecv" line inside of the 'try' case it works. I would've thought the code would execute past the 'catch' if there were no exceptions thrown. I'm confused

Comment: @David - well, I posted an answer but seems like you found the problem as well. You were shadowing your class variable with a local variable of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem of instance shadowing. You declare a new variable in your method, in the try block, with the ***same*** name as a class variable. So, the class variable is *shadowed* and thus, never initialized. When you later return it from the method, its null.

```
public class EnvConfig {

    private String rawJSONString;
    private JSONObject jsonObjRecv; // <-- you declare a class variable here

    // ...

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(rawJSONString); // <-- shadowed here!
```

Unless you are trying to avoid re-parsing the JSON repeatedly, I would advise getting rid of the class variables altogether. Otherwise, get rid of the local variable.

Comment: ahhhh i see that now. thanks! i've never even heard of instance shadowing. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I use for Parsing my JSON Data, I am not familiar with the JSONConfig that you are using, however this works prefectly for me.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(/*Json String Data*/).nextValue();
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(/*Name of JSON Array*/);
```